# R Count How Many Time `auto.arima()` Confirm`arima.sim()` to be True

Tags: r, count, arima

Often times I make use of `arima.sim()` function to simulate `ARIMA` model and later discover through `auto.arima()` function that the `ARIMA` model simulated is not the same with what I specified in `arima.sim()` function.

I went further to investigate to know how does the `arima.sim()` fair in simulating `ARIMA` model by simulating same `ARIMA` model with the same `arima.sim()` detail good number of times and then check each out with `auto.arima()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62545589/i-want-to-simulate-and-obtain-best-arima-ith-number-of-time-in-r/62548442#62548442).

```
result <- matrix(NA_integer_, nrow = 10, ncol = 3)
colnames(result) <- c("p","d","q")
num<-60
set.seed(1234)
for(i in 1:10){
   result[i, ] <- arima.sim(n = num, model=list(ar=0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0))) %>%
     auto.arima() %>%
     arimaorder()
}
result
#p  d   q
#1  0   1
#1  0   0
#1  0   0
#1  0   0
#2  0   1
#1  0   0
#1  0   0
#1  0   0
#1  0   0
#4  0   3
```

How do I put up an `R` code that will count how many
times `ARIMA(1, 0, 0)` comes up when I run

```
num<-60
for(i in 1:10){
   ar1 <- arima.sim(n = num, model=list(ar=0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)))
     auto.arima(ar1)
}
```

ten(10) times in a `loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to get the `count` within the `for` loop

```
cnt <- 0
for(i in 1:10) { 
   ar1 <- arima.sim(n = num, model=list(ar=0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)))
   ar2 <- auto.arima(ar1)
   if(all(arimaorder(ar2) == c(1, 0, 0))) cnt <- cnt + 1}
cnt
#[1] 3
```

---

Or if it is based on the 'result', then do a comparison with the vector, get the `rowSums`, and check if we have 3 TRUE in a single row, and `sum`

```
sum(rowSums(result == c(1, 0, 0)[col(result)]) == 3)
```